# How to able and disable a function through events

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I created a DIV and some input fields within it dynamically using DOM.
Then I applied a function to be able to move it:

```js
document.getElementById('thedivtomove').addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  mydragfunction.startMoving(this, "thedivcontainer", event);
});
document.getElementById('thedivtomove').addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  mydragfunction.stopMoving("thedivcontainer");
});
```

I would like to disable it (moving) when I click in the fields (input, combos etc.) but I can't reach this goal despite the most varied ways.

The way that would seem most logical to me would be to invert the events (up & down)

```js
    document.getElementById('thefield').addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      mydragfunction.stopMoving("thedivcontainer");
    });
    document.getElementById('thefield').addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      mydragfunction.startMoving("theboxtomove", "thedivcontainer", event);
    });
```

by hovering over the fields but this choice seems to not work. I do not report about to all the other attempts because I find them to be freaky (combinations of various events, introduction of flags, etc.)

Comment: Could you also post the working HTML code so far in a Snippet or Fiddle ?

Answer (score -1):

Ok first for the same type event, `click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup` on the same context or element there is an order of execution.

> In cases when a single action initiates multiple events, their order is fixed. That is, the handlers are called in the order mousedown → mouseup → click. Events are handled in the same sequence: onmouseup finishes before onclick runs.

Then you need to think about UI and and tools the DOM and browser give to you.

An example to achieve your goal, i could use the focus state of an input to disable your events:

```
const divToMove = document.getElementById('thedivtomove');
const inputs    = divToMove.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.addEventListener('focus', removerListener);
inputs.addEventListener('focusout', listenMove);

const listenMove = () => {
  divToMove.addEventListener('mousedown', mydragfunction.startMoving.bind(this, 'thedivcontainer'));
  divToMove.addEventListener('mouseup', mydragfunction.stopMoving.bind(this, 'thedivcontainer'));
}

const removeListener = () => {
  divToMove.removeEventListener('mousedown, mydragfunction.startMoving);
  divToMove.removeEventListener('mouseup', mydragfunction.stopMoving);
}
```

Take care about the bind function which allow you to define the context to use inside a function. So your `mydragfunction.startMoving(this, "thedivcontainer", event);` will not change the signature but i don't pass the event object in the bind call. This will be automatically pass by the implementation of your brower events.